# Suddenly extra index value in my array

Tags: c++, arrays

My code is:

```
char randomChar(int randMax) {
    return (65 + rand() % randMax);
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    const int SIZE = 4;
    const int LETTERS = 6;
    char code[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        code[i] = randomChar(LETTERS);
    }

    cout << code;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that even though I've set the code-array to be of length 4, the `randomChar` function returns 4 letters + some extra random sign.

Comment: get rid of those ugly char arrays and use a `std::string`. You won't have this kind of problem any more. Use the beauty of C++, where pointers and plain arrays are wrapped into a safe playground.

Comment: We haven't learned pointers in my class yet :/

Comment: Even better. You won't need it in the beginning phase of learning C++. You don't need to know anything about pointers to use std::string.

Answer (score 2):

You should put a terminating zero character in the array. Otherwise you may get junk printed after the end of the array. Always declare the array with size 1 more than you need and then set the last element to 0.

Try this code:

```
char randomChar(int randMax) {
    return (65 + rand() % randMax);
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    const int SIZE = 4;
    const int LETTERS = 6;
    char code[SIZE + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        code[i] = randomChar(LETTERS);
    }

    code[SIZE] = 0; // or '\0'
    cout << code;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to initialize `code` like that `char code[SIZE + 1] = {0};`

Comment: In this case yes, but I attempted to give a general explanation. Just initializing with zero will not always be enough(for instance if re-using the char array in a cycle). Zero terminating a character string is something that should always be done.

Comment: Hmmm... Indeed. Didn't think about it

Comment: Can you use 0? I always through you had to use `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not zero terminated.

You probably have to do this:

```
char randomChar(int randMax) {
    return (65 + rand() % randMax);
}

int main() {

srand(time(NULL));
const int SIZE = 4;
const int LETTERS = 6;
char code[SIZE + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    code[i] = randomChar(LETTERS);
}

code[SIZE] = '\0';
cout << code;


return 0;
}
```

or, as recommended by commenter @borisbn:

```
char randomChar(int randMax) {
    return (65 + rand() % randMax);
}

int main() {

srand(time(NULL));
const int SIZE = 4;
const int LETTERS = 6;
char code[SIZE + 1] = {0};

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    code[i] = randomChar(LETTERS);
}

cout << code;


return 0;
}
```

However if there's any universe out there in which ('\0' != 0) is true, this latter would fail there.

Comment: Nope not `SIZE+1`, just size(when adding the 0)

Comment: It would be better to initialize `code` like that `char code[SIZE + 1] = {0};`

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you're not null-terminating your char array. You can forget about this kind of problem if you use the proper C++ way, i.e. by using `std::string` which is basically a wrapper class for char arrays. Here's how to implement the same logic in C++:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char randomChar(const int randMax) // suggestion, not a necessity: mark randMax as const since you never intend to modify it here.
{
    return ( 65 + std::rand() % randMax );
}

int main()
{
   std::srand(std::time(NULL));
   const int SIZE = 4;
   const int LETTERS = 6;
   std::string code;
   for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
   {
       code.insert(code.end(), randomChar(LETTERS));
   }
   std::cout << code << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings are zero-terminated this is because the length of a string is not associated with it so there needed to be some way of determining where the string ended. C and C++ do this by placing a zero character at the end of the string. When you do something like `char* text = "simples";` the compiler will do this for you but when you're generating your own strings you need to leave space for one more character after the ones you're interested in and set this character to `\0`.

The reason you're getting spurious characters at the end is that `cout` is dutifully printing out characters starting with your array until it happens to hit a zero byte which it will interpret as the end of the string.

Thus you want to replace your `main()` function with this:

```
int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    const int SIZE = 4;
    const int LETTERS = 6;
    char code[SIZE + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        code[i] = randomChar(LETTERS);
    }

    // Need to zero-terminate the string
    code[SIZE] = '\0';
    cout << code;

    return 0;
}
```

(You could also do `code[SIZE] = 0` but I prefer the expressiveness of `\0` - both will produce exactly the same effect)

Zero-termination is also one of the principle reasons that string handling in C and C++ is slower than it could be: nearly every string operation needs to scan the string from beginning to end to find the null-terminator.